# How can I force animations in UITableViewCells to stop while scrolling through the table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

The problem I face itself is simple to describe.

I have a table view in my application in which animations are started asynchronously. And for once index path, the animations happen only once. If I scroll the cell out of visible area, I assume that the animation for that index path are finished. i.e. Next time the index path comes back to the visible area, I set it to the final values without animation. If I do not scroll, the animations work as expected.

However, when I scroll the table view, because the cell is reused and the animations intended to be performed on the cells currently not visible are still being performed on the now visible cell.
I have put together a sample code that describes my problem.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn) { [weak cell] in
            cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
        } completion: { [weak cell] _ in
            cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn) { [weak cell] in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
            } completion: { [weak cell] _ in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
            }
        }
        animated[indexPath.row].toggle()
        return cell
    }
}
```

To stop the animation if the cell goes out of bounds of the table view, I tried to save a reference of the animation in the cell and remove right after a cell is dequeued. But it doesn't help my case.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    var animated: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: 100)
}

class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var animations: [UIViewPropertyAnimator] = []
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
        
        if !animated[indexPath.row] {
            
            //Stop animations if any
            cell.animations.forEach { animator in
                animator.stopAnimation(true)
            }
            cell.animations.removeAll()

            //
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, curve: .easeIn) { [weak cell] in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
            }
            
            animator.addCompletion { [weak cell] completed in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
                
                if completed == .end {
                    
                    let animator1 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, curve: .easeIn) { [weak cell] in
                        cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
                    }
                    
                    animator1.addCompletion { [weak cell] _ in
                        cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
                        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
                    }
                    
                    animator1.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0)
                    cell?.animations.append(animator1)
                }
            }
            
            animator.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0)
            cell.animations.append(animator)
            
            animated[indexPath.row].toggle()
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

I could not find anything similar on SO. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add the animator in cell class and use prepareForReuse in cell to stop it

Comment: Are you trying to "pause" the animation when the cell scrolls out of view, and then "resume" it when the cell scrolls back into view?

Comment: @DonMag no, if the cell scrolls out of the visible area, I assume that the animation is complete for that index path. And the animation needs to happen once and only once for a single index path.

Answer (score 1):

Set/stop animation in cell class :

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    var animation : UIViewPropertyAnimator?

    // call this in cellForRow in tableView controller 
    func startAnimation() {
        … create animation and save it in self.animation
    }

    func stopAnimation () {
        … stop animation 
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        StopAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is similar to what I did? . But I have some nested animation. Like the one I described in the second chunk of code. When I do that the second aimation runs regardless.

Comment: You can add the nested animation in your completion handler in the cell class. You only have to save the last animation as when you create the second one your first animation is in the completion handler (ie terminated). You also do not reset the opacity before animating.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an odd animation sequence, but I'm guessing this is more for testing / figuring it out for your actual use.

This might help...

Implement `prepareForReuse()` in your cell to stop and remove any executing animations, and set the label's opacity to `1.0`.

In `cellForRowAt`, set the slot in your `animated` array to **false** instead of toggling it, since you only want the animation to run the first time a row appears.

Also in `cellForRowAt`, make sure you "reset" the cell's label to its initial value.

Give this a try and see if it gets you closer to your goal:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var animations: [UIViewPropertyAnimator] = []
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        animations.forEach { animator in
            animator.stopAnimation(true)
        }
        animations.removeAll()

        textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1.0
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    var animated: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: 100)
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
        
        if !animated[indexPath.row] {
            
            animated[indexPath.row] = true
            
            // cells are reused, so "reset" the initial label text
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Needs to animate..."

            //
            let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, curve: .easeIn) { [weak cell] in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
            }
            
            animator.addCompletion { [weak cell] completed in
                cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 0
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
                
                if completed == .end {
                    
                    let animator1 = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, curve: .easeIn) { [weak cell] in
                        cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
                    }
                    
                    animator1.addCompletion { [weak cell] _ in
                        cell?.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
                        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
                    }
                    
                    animator1.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0)
                    cell?.animations.append(animator1)
                }
            }
            
            animator.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0)
            cell.animations.append(animator)
            
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.layer.opacity = 1
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

Note on animator completion blocks...

First, you used `completed` as your completion block parameter -- you might be misleading yourself, as it's not a Bool value... it's a `UIViewAnimatingPosition` value.

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648373-addcompletion):

> The ending position of the animations. Use this value to determine whether the animations stopped at the beginning, end, or somewhere in the middle.

> Completion blocks are executed after the animations finish normally. If you call the stopAnimation(_:) method, the completion blocks are not called if you specify true for the method’s parameter. If you specify false for the parameter, the animator executes the completion blocks normally after you call the its finishAnimation(at:) method.

So, if your

```
animator.stopAnimation(true)
```

is called *before* the first animation finishes, its completion block will not be called.

If it's called *after* the first animation finishes, but *before* the second animation finishes, the second animation's completion block will not be called.

Comment: This should theoretically work, but on the line **if completed == .end {**, if we were scrolling the table view the condition should fail, but the **completed** variable here is **.end**, which is confounding. Is this a bug? Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the variable?
Basically the first animation **animator** terminates as expected, but the second animation **animator1** starts, which isn't desired

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, this works. But any idea why **completion** still is **.end**?